# find indexof single character in string c#

Tags: c#, string

I am confused with this code.

```
string str = sample.indexof("a",0);
```

It's working. But below not working.

```
string str = sample.indexof("\",0);
```

Comment: in both of this query replace string with int becuase return type of indexof is index value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape backslashes in string and character literals in C# - or use a verbatim string literal. Any of these will work:

```
int index = sample.IndexOf("\\", 0);
int index = sample.IndexOf(@"\", 0);
int index = sample.IndexOf('\\', 0);
```

Or without specifying the initial index, if you're looking from the start anyway:

```
int index = sample.IndexOf("\\");
int index = sample.IndexOf(@"\");
int index = sample.IndexOf('\\');
```

Personally I would use the last of these if you're only looking for a single character - it's clearer that it really *is* exactly one character. (It may be marginally more efficient too, but the clarity is more important.)

(Note that C# is case sensitive - it's [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx), not `indexof`. Also note that it returns `int`, not `string`. It helps if you can make your sample code accurate...)

Answer (score 1):

because \ is escape sequence char you can try out one of the below option to work

```
int i = sample.indexof("\\",0)
```

or

```
int i = sample.IndexOf(@"\", 0);
```